# Mysql Column 'nume' in field list is ambiguous error

Tags: mysql

```
select nume as "Nume", adresa as "Adresa",localitate as "Localitatea"
from info 
left join angajati 
on id_i = id_a
where localitate like "Orhei" 
and year(curdate()) - year(data_nast) >=50
```

I have 2 tables with nume field and i'm getting the error, please help i don't now why this code didn't work !!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since you are joining on the `id_i` and `id_a` columns, the two `nume` columns are distinct in the joined result. Specify which table's `nume` column you mean:

```
SELECT info.nume AS "Nume" ...
```

or

```
SELECT angajati.nume AS "Nume" ...
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to define which table the `nume` field should be coming from.  Here's one way using a table alias:

```
select i.nume as "Nume", 
       adresa as "Adresa",
       localitate as "Localitatea"
from info i 
    left join angajati a on id_i = id_a
where localitate like "Orhei" 
     and year(curdate()) - year(data_nast) >=50
```

When using `joins`, if the same field is represented in multiple tables, you have to define which table you are referring to.

Comment: mysql  is returning an empty result set (i.e. zero rows) maybe  something i messed up, help please !!! i want go to sleep ...